# AttributeError in dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I found a way that can possibly allow me to get the keys of my dictionary using value with this :

```
mydic.keys()[mydic.values().index(value)]
```

My code is below:

```
def déchiffrement(code, dico):
    taille3 = len(code)
    décodé = []
    for i in range(taille3):
        décodé.insert(i, dico.keys()[dico.values().index(code[i])])
    return décodé
```

`dico` is a dictionary looking like this:

```
dico = {
    "A": [1, 9],
    "B": [12, 19],
    ...
    "Z": [78, 108],
}
```

and `code` is a list of numbers that corresponds to a letter. The numbers in `dico` are never the same.

However, I get an

> AttributeError: 'dict_values' object has no attribute 'index'

which I don't understand because this code seems to work on other people's codes.

Comment: Since Python3, `dict.values()` returns an iterator instead of a list for efficiency, similar to Python2's `dict.itervalues()`.

Comment: @muraveill: to be exact, `dict.values()` in Python 3 is the equivalent of `dict.viewvalues()` in 2.

Comment: Okay, so it's just a matter of version ? How can I correct it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Orange's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36093305/1391671) and the comments on your question comments are correct; you are (presumably) using Python 3, where `dict.values()` returns a [dictionary view object](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/stdtypes.html#dict-views) instead of a `list`, and does not provide the `index()` function.

---

However, it appears that you are looking to map every code *separately* back to the original character. For this, it is much cleaner to pre-compute the decoder:

```
def invert(dico):
    # map values to keys, note the nested comprehension
    return {i: k for k, v in dico.items() for i in v}

def decipher(code, dico):
    # note that this result can be cached or even just
    # computed outside the function
    decoder = invert(dico)

    # pass each code through the decoder map
    return [decoder[c] for c in code]

print decipher([1, 9, 108], {
    'A': [1, 9],
    'B': [12, 19],
    'C': [78, 108]
})
```

which outputs

```
['A', 'A', 'C']
```

Comment: This solution won't work for me I'm afraid. The value are used a crypted letter and I must be able to get the letter asigned to ONE number, not the whole list.

Comment: Understood (although note that your code with Orange's correction will do the same thing as mine). Do you mean that given the dictionary above, `1` and `9` must both map to `'A'`?

Comment: Exactly. This is how I will decrypt the message. (I encrypt it with the same dictionary).

Comment: I see. Then please see my edited answer. `dict.keys()` and `dict.values()` will do nothing to _flatten_ the lists in the dictionary values, you need something like the nested dict comprehension I wrote in the `invert` function.

Comment: Please consider editing your question with an example of the desired behavior (for future visitors). It is not clear that you wanted to map characters to single numbers, and your original code does not really indicate that it's your end goal.

Answer (score 0):

`index` is a function of `list`, not of a `dict_values` object returned by `dico.values()`. So, change your code so that `dico.values()` is converted to a list:

```
def déchiffrement(code,dico):
    taille3 = len(code)
    décodé = []
    for i in range(taille3):
        décodé.insert(i, dico.keys()[list(dico.values()).index(code[i])]) # Changed here
    return décodé
```

Comment: It is worth noting that it might work in other people's code because in Python2, `dico.values()` would return a list.

Comment: Is this a difference new to python 3? My `type(mydict.values())` is `<type 'list'>
` ... edit: I was 15sec too late :)

Comment: It won't affect the fact that I need to extract the keys ? Edit : Tried it, tell me a value i search is not in the list but it is.

Comment: I changed for what you said, still tell me that a number (46 here) is not in the list, but when I look Inside the dictionary, it is here. Maybe it is because each value is a list of number ?